# Installing Android Studio for Android development

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just downloaded the early access of Android Studio. While trying to run, I had to modify the environment variable and add

> JAVA_HOME

and

> C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.6.0_07

Once I finished that hurdle, now I am receiving another error:

```
The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of *C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.6.0_07*) does not point to a valid JVM installation.
```

I looked through other similar question and was asked to check the version, so I did the following in CMD:

```
C:\Windows\System32>java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

From the result it seems like I have JVM. If I don't where do I download the JVM from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `JAVA_HOME` to your JDK folder, not your JRE folder.  If you don't have an installed JDK, go download it (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: wow! worked for me

I set the `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25` and it worked.

Thanks!!